# How relevant is the electric charge of quarks within hadrons?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force

Given that each quark flavor has a particular electric charge (i.e., either +2/3 or -1/3): how do these charges effect the internal dynamics of hadrons? Do the attractive and repulsive effects of electromagnetism play a meaningful role in hadron dynamics (e.g., how protons (uud) and neutrons (udd) remain relatively stable), or does the strength of the strong force completely dominate these dynamics?

In other words, what is the overall role and effect of electromagnetism within (i.e., within the interior of, rather than external to) hadrons?

Comment: Hint: [Isospin symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin).

Comment: The charge radius of the neutron is negative….

Answer (score 1):

As a rough order of magnitude estimate you may consider the ratio $\frac{m_n-m_p}{m_p} \simeq 0.0013$, i.e. electromagnetism and the $u,d$ quark mass difference affect this ratio only at the  per mille level.

An even better example is the ratio $\frac{M_\pi^\pm-M_\pi^0}{M_\pi}\simeq 0.03$, being practically a purely electromagnetic effect as contributions originating from the $u,d$ quark mass difference are heavily suppressed in that case.

Comment: According to https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34262/219989, " it's mostly the fact that the down quark is heavier than the up quark that makes the neutron heavier than the proton" - not the different charge.

Comment: @NadavHar'El I have now included now both effects in my answer.

Comment: For a long time, QCD simulations simply ignored the electromagnetic interaction as being too small a perturbation. A first estimate by considering the nuclei as a roughly constant charge density liquid drop provides a great averaged contribution. Only in the recent decade have people started to add the perturbation of actual QED interaction to the behaviour of quarks.